# How to get access to another qt widget function?

Tags: python, qt, oop

I am working on a Qt/Python program, which includes one QMainWindow, that also has two widgets (Let's call them Widget A and Widget B).

I would like to get some value by running "someFunction()" which is arranged in Widget A from Widget B. So, I tried the following code in the constructor of Widget B:

```
self.someValue = self.parent().findChild(WidgetB).someFunction()
```

But it do not work at all. If I run this function in the constructor I do not even get any error or something.

Could someone explain this behaviour? Or better, tell me how to run this function in another widget!?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

The problem was, that the parent-widget in the constructor has another parent than the rest of the class... or something like this.. but anyway, here is the code that worked properly:

```
self.parent().parent().findChild(widgets.WidgetA).someFunction()
```

Hope that I can help anyone who also has this problem!